# Book (series?) with a protagonist discriminated against for having no magic, later revealed to have light-based (invisible) magic

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I remember reading a book or series where the protagonist was discriminated against for not having a visible magic. It's revealed later that his/her magic is light-based, which is why it has no color.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Any chance you could add some more details to your question? Things like language, when you bought it/read it, something distinctive on the cover, etc. Even the smallest detail could help.

Comment: I read a manga where this was the case with the main character. It was called "Psychic Academy." Are you looking for a novel or could it be a manga?

Answer (score 4):

Could it be Piers Anthony's [*A Spell for Chameleon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Spell_for_Chameleon) (1977)?

Bink apparently has no magic, so he's discriminated against and eventually banished. Later it turns out he does have magic (magical resistance).

Comment: Isn't Bink's talent that nothing magical can harm him? This doesn't really fit with the question.

Comment: @JohnRennie yes thats correct so it appears he has no magic.

Comment: Right, but it's not light-based magic.